# list-comprehension syntax for functions

Tags: python

Is there a way of using the list-comprehension "syntax" in functions, to reduce calculation/calls (a bit like try/catch) e.g a way of writing

```py
customers=dict

for customer in customers:
  if movie not in customers[customer]:
          customers[customer].append(movie)
```

as

```py
for customer in customers:
  p.append(movie) if movie not in p=customers[customer]
```

if the call/operation `p` was very heavy, thus it makes a big deal, if it is called once or twice

Comment: `p` already exists as `customer` does it not? list comprehensions should be used when you want a list as an output, not to reduce lines of code

Comment: You are effectively trying to use a comprehension for its side effects (appending to existing lists), which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).

Comment: it is not about list-comprehension, but to reduce the call `customers[customer]` from two to one

Comment: Loop the values instead of the keys, also, you can get more performance by using a `set` for `movies` instead of a list

Answer (score 3):

You can use  the `items` method of a dict in a list comprehension:

```
[ expression for key,val in customers.items() ]
```

so you could abuse it to have the side-effect of appending:

```
[ val.append(movie) for key,val in customers.items() if movie not in val ]
```

The actual value of the list-comprehension is almost useless: it'll be a list of `None` (but its length will tell you how many `val` did not contain `movie`).

Sometimes, shorter is not better style. I think this may be one of them.

Edit: just realised `key` is unused, so the `.values()` method is better (I find a use for it so rarely I forgot about it!)

```
[ val.append(movie) for val in customers.values() if movie not in val ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of "calculation/calls" you are trying to reduce, but if it is the double lookup of `customers[customer]`, you can do it like this:

```
for movies in customers.values():
    if movie not in movies:
        movies.append(movie)
```

.values() iterates over the values of the dict (so in your case, the list of movies for each customer), so it avoids iterating on the customers and looking up the list of movies twice. That works assuming `customers` is a `dict` of `list`s as values.
You can even enhance that with a `dict` of `set`s:

```
for movies in customers.values():
   movies.add(movie)
```

Comment: It is for each `customer` i want to check, if that movie is already in his list, i.e
the call `customers[customer]` (list of movies) is called twice: one for checking if `movie` is in that list and once more when we append it.

Answer (score 0):

## One-line code:

```py
[movies.append(movie) for movies in customers.values() if movie not in movies]
```

---

`dict.values()` returns a list-like object of the values of a dictionary, excluding the keys. The line above evaluates a list of return values of `list.append`, but `list.append` returns `None`, and the list is discarded anyways.

---

What I recommend is to actually write out the full logic:

```py
for movies in customers.values():
    if movie not in movies:
        movies.append(movie)
```

and to use list comprehension *only when you actually need the list*. It will only confuse those who don't understand list comprehension, and it does not provide any speedup or cleaner code.

Also, if you don't want repeating items in a `list`, consider a `set`, which contains distinct elements and provides a speedup.